# ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception whilst (before?) executing JSP using GAE

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I have happily using/developing with GAE for well over a year. 
Suddenly none of my JSP pages work with local debugging.
I suspect the updating of SDK/JDKs but how to rectify the situation eludes me. 
Any ideas anyone??

After

```
jsp = req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp");
jsp.forward(req, resp);
```

I get the following stack trace:-

```
Clock [Web Application] 
    com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain at localhost:58357  
        Thread [main] (Running) 
        Thread [26975285@qtp-1294089382-0] (Suspended (exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException))   
            owns: MethodDescriptor  (id=423)    
            owns: JspServletWrapper  (id=424)   
            SignatureParser.current() line: 95  
            SignatureParser.parseZeroOrMoreThrowsSignatures() line: 635 
            SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature() line: 577    
            SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(String) line: 173    
            MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).parse(String) line: 55  
            MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).parse(String) line: 43  
            MethodRepository(AbstractRepository<T>).<init>(String, GenericsFactory) line: 74    
            MethodRepository(GenericDeclRepository<S>).<init>(String, GenericsFactory) line: 48 
            MethodRepository(ConstructorRepository).<init>(String, GenericsFactory) line: 51    
            MethodRepository.<init>(String, GenericsFactory) line: 46   
            MethodRepository.make(String, GenericsFactory) line: 59 
            Method.getGenericInfo() line: 102   
            Method.getGenericParameterTypes() line: 292 
            FeatureDescriptor.getParameterTypes(Class, Method) line: 387    
            MethodDescriptor.setMethod(Method) line: 114    
            MethodDescriptor.<init>(Method, ParameterDescriptor[]) line: 72 
            MethodDescriptor.<init>(Method) line: 56    
            Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo() line: 1149   
            Introspector.getBeanInfo() line: 416    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>) line: 163    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>, Class<?>, int) line: 250 
            Introspector.<init>(Class, Class, int) line: 397    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>) line: 163    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>, Class<?>, int) line: 250 
            Introspector.<init>(Class, Class, int) line: 397    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>) line: 163    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>, Class<?>, int) line: 250 
            Introspector.<init>(Class, Class, int) line: 397    
            Introspector.getBeanInfo(Class<?>) line: 163    
            Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Node, Class, ErrorDispatcher) line: 3888    
            Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Node$CustomTag) line: 2155  
            Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Node$CustomTag) line: 1628  
            Node$CustomTag.accept(Node$Visitor) line: 1530  
            Node$Nodes.visit(Node$Visitor) line: 2361   
            Generator$GenerateVisitor(Node$Visitor).visitBody(Node) line: 2411  
            Generator$GenerateVisitor(Node$Visitor).visit(Node$Root) line: 2417 
            Node$Root.accept(Node$Visitor) line: 495    
            Node$Nodes.visit(Node$Visitor) line: 2361   
            Generator.generate(ServletWriter, Compiler, Node$Nodes) line: 3440  
            JDTCompiler(Compiler).generateJava() line: 231  
            JDTCompiler(Compiler).compile(boolean, boolean) line: 347   
            JDTCompiler(Compiler).compile(boolean) line: 327    
            JDTCompiler(Compiler).compile() line: 314   
            JspCompilationContext.compile() line: 592   
            JspServletWrapper.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, boolean) line: 317   
            PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).serviceJspFile(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, String, Throwable, boolean) line: 313  
            PrivilegedJspServlet(JspServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 260 
            PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 23 
            PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run() line: 61   
            AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>) line: not available [native method] 
            PrivilegedJspServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 58  
            PrivilegedJspServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717    
            ServletHolder.handle(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 511 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1166 
            ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 63 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(String, int, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 366  
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 349 
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 116  
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            ServletHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 388   
            SecurityHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 216  
            SessionHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 182   
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext(ContextHandler).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 765    
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 418 
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 98 
            Dispatcher.forward(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, int) line: 327  
            Dispatcher.forward(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 126   
            ClockServlet.getcust(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, GcsService) line: 1932    
            ClockServlet.doGet(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 639   
            ClockServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 617    
            ClockServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 717    
            ServletHolder.handle(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 511 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1166 
            DevSocketFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 74 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 127 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 34    
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 63 
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 43    
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            StaticFileFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 125   
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(String, int, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 366  
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 349 
            DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 116  
            ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 1157 
            ServletHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 388   
            SecurityHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 216  
            SessionHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 182   
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext(ContextHandler).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 765    
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext(WebAppContext).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 418 
            DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 98 
            JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler(HandlerWrapper).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 152    
            JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 491    
            Server(HandlerWrapper).handle(String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, int) line: 152   
            Server.handle(HttpConnection) line: 326 
            HttpConnection.handleRequest() line: 542    
            HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete() line: 923    
            HttpParser.parseNext() line: 547    
            HttpParser.parseAvailable() line: 212   
            HttpConnection.handle() line: 404   
            SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorEndPoint(SelectChannelEndPoint).run() line: 409 
            QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run() line: 582 
        Thread [694563922@qtp-1294089382-1 - Acceptor0 SelectChannelConnector@127.0.0.1:8888] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [Timer-0] (Running)   
        Daemon Thread [Timer-1] (Running)   
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\javaw.exe (21 Aug 2014 09:57:15)
```

}

Comment: Just tried again and it worked OK???? What did I do??

Comment: I deleted all breakpoints!!

Answer (score 2):

I deleted all breakpoints, it then worked.